# Python3 decode greek letter from binary file

Tags: python, python-3.x, decode, binaryfiles

I have a binary file, and want to read and decode the file. The file uses one byte for each character. I had an error when decoding the part with a greek letter. Since I cannot share the file, you can use the sample code below for your own testing. The issue is the UnicodeDecodeError.

```
data = b'a5'
data.decode("utf-8")
'a5'
data = b'a5\xb5'
data.decode("utf-8")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5
```

**Solution:**

```
data = b'a5\xb5'
data.decode("windows-1252")
'a5µ'
```

Comment: `\xb5` by itself is not valid UTF-8. You must have chopped off the input.

Comment: What are you looking to do with the data?

Comment: "The file uses one byte for each character" *flat out* contradicts your use of UTF8 in your code.

Comment: I found the answer. It should be decoded with windows-1252.

Comment: Then write it *as an answer* – there is a big box for that – and don't put it inside the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading a unicode string, not a UTF8 bytestring:

```
# UTF8 bytestring
data = b'\xc2\xb5'
data.decode("utf-8")
>>> 'µ'
```

```
# Unicode string:
data = '\xb5'
data
>>> 'µ'
```

You should open your file like so (in python 3 files are automatically decoded to unicode (text) provided you supply the encoding):

```
with open(filename, encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.seek(24, 0)
    datastr_size = unpack('B', f.read(1))[0]
    datastr = ""
    for i in range(datastr_size):
        data = unpack('c', f.read(1))[0] #decode("utf-8") not needed
        datastr += data
    datastr
```

- http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=U%2B00b5

Comment: What about string `b'a5\xb5'`?

Comment: Forgive me. So how to read it as unicode string under binary mode if `data  = b'\xb5'`?

Comment: I added the code I used. As for the format of the file, I am not entirely sure. The file is from vendor, and I was able to read under 'rb' mode not 'r' mode. 'r' mode returns UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap'codec can't decode bytes 0x9d.

Comment: Same error as I posted. UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5

Comment: I found the answer and have updated my solution above. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean by a "unicode string"? If it's in a file, it can't be an unencoded sequence of unicode character objects; it has to be in some encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Need the correct decoding.

```
data = b'a5\xb5'
data.decode("windows-1252")
'a5µ'
```